# inherit abstract class in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, abstract

I know that multiple inheritance not supported in c#.But I want to inherit method from abstract class by keeping  System.Web.UI.Page as it is.for example..

```
abstract class stuff1()
{
 public abstract void print();
}
```

in aspx page

```
 public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   //I want to implement print() method from abstract class here
  }
```

Can we inherit methods from abstract class in code behind aspx.cs file,If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending your class from System.Web.UI.Page class. In this way, your web pages can inherit from your class and can extend the functionality.

```
public abstract class stuff1 : Page
{
    public abstract void print();
}


public partial class _Default : stuff1
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public override void print()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```